# Approximately equal too symbol operations permitted

Tags: approximation

I have to doubt to clear if A is approximately to 2/3 B can I write it as A approximately equal to 4/6 B? Since it is approximate relation is it permitted to multiply both numerator and denominator as with equal to relationship?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether it's $\approx$ or $=$. You can always multiply both numerator and denominator of a fraction. We have

$$\frac 23=\frac 46$$

and that's it.